# Displaying Deezer user playlists in Android app

Tags: android, deezer

I'm working on a small Android player I have found on github.

I managed to compile the code, but I'm using the 0.10.16 SDK. it seems the player on github was written for a previous version.

I can log in but when I click on Playlists on the home screen and the code bellow executes, I get a blank screen:

```
   private void getUserPlaylists() {
    DeezerRequest request = DeezerRequestFactory.requestCurrentUserPlaylists();
    AsyncDeezerTask task = new AsyncDeezerTask(mDeezerConnect,
            new JsonRequestListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void onResult(final Object result, final Object requestId) {

                    mPlaylistList.clear();

                    try {
                        mPlaylistList.addAll((List<Playlist>) result);
                    }
                    catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        handleError(e);
                    }

                    if (mPlaylistList.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(UserPlaylistsActivity.this, getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.no_results), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    mPlaylistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(final String response, Object requestId) {
                    //TODO
                    Toast.makeText(UserPlaylistsActivity.this, "Playlist_onComplete",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }


                @Override
                public void onUnparsedResult(final String response, Object requestId) {
                    //TODO
                }


                @Override
                public void onException(Exception exception, Object requestId) {


                    if(exception instanceof OAuthException){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else if(exception instanceof MalformedURLException){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else if(exception instanceof IOException){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else if(exception instanceof DeezerError){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else if(exception instanceof JSONException){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else{
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }


            });
    task.execute(request);
}
```

I think the reason is, that the code above was written for the previous SDK version, which apparently worked with "onResult". The latest SDK however works with "onComplete", which returns an unparsed JSON string.

My questions are:

- is there a class built into the SDK that will parse the JSON response
- is there a class that will accept the parsed response
- is there a function that will display this on screen

I was looking through the documentation, but did not find anything useful.

Did anyone implement this with the latest SDK?

EDIT:

```
private void getUserPlaylists() {
    DeezerRequest request = DeezerRequestFactory.requestCurrentUserPlaylists();
    AsyncDeezerTask task = new AsyncDeezerTask(mDeezerConnect,
            new JsonRequestListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void onResult(final Object result, final Object requestId) {

                    mPlaylistList.clear();

                    try {
                        mPlaylistList.addAll((List<Playlist>) result);
                    }
                    catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        handleError(e);
                    }

                    if (mPlaylistList.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(UserPlaylistsActivity.this, getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.no_results), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    mPlaylistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }



                @Override
                public void onUnparsedResult(final String response, Object requestId) {
                    //TODO
                }


                @Override
                public void onException(Exception exception, Object requestId) {


                    if(exception instanceof OAuthException){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else if(exception instanceof MalformedURLException){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else if(exception instanceof IOException){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else if(exception instanceof DeezerError){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else if(exception instanceof JSONException){
                        handleError(exception);
                    }
                    else{
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }


            });
    task.execute(request);
}
```

This works now with 0.10.16 SDK. Removed onComplete() and all data is now beeing parsed correctly. Menus are OK, playback is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're overriding the `onComplete(String, Object)` method. This method is already present in the `JsonRequestListener` implementation, so you should not rewrite it yourself, at least not without calling `super.onComplete(response, requestId)`.

When overriding the `JsonResultListener` class, you should only implement the `onResult(Object, Object)` as you did, the `onUnparsedResult(String, Object)` method in case the json can't be parsed automatically, and the `onException(Exception, Object)` in case an exception occurs.

Comment: Yes, that one did the trick. The app now works correctly. Thanks!